# Can a pipe property affect the length of air flow?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, air

Sorry about the bad title, I'm not even sure how to call that so I'm having trouble researching it, but I made a picture.

Let say you blow through a pipe, other than how strong you blow into it, is there something that you can change about the pipe to affect how far it will blow?

[image]

Comment: Please add some more details and assumptions that every time how strong one blow is the same for people to understand what you specifically need.

Comment: While you're making that change (please _edit your question_), tell us what constraints you're putting on the pipe -- i.e., length limitation, diameter limitations, must it be constant diameter, does it have to be made from physically possible materials, etc.

Comment: I cannot answer your question, but if it helps you any in your search, I think that what comes out of the free end of the pipe is a [_laminar flow_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laminar_flow), and you are asking, under what conditions does a laminar stream of air that's moving through a body of still air "break up" and become [_turbulent_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbulence). Maybe this Wikipedia article will help you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_number

Answer (score 0):

Beside the length also the diameter of the pipe, the form of the cross-section, the roughness of the inner wall, the precise form of the tube ending and some more subtle aspects influence the length of the laminar flow.

Please refine your question a bit to tell us what your aim is.

Do you want to know how to achieve the "longest blow" in your words?
Then we also need to find an agreement about where this length ends, because the flow degrades over distance.